# Add a row to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation, row, addition

I have a matrix `A` like

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

and I want to expand it with a row of ones to get

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

I create the row of ones with

```
col_size = size(A, 2); 
ones_row = ones(1, col_size);
```

How can I add my `ones_row` to the matrix?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Once you have `A` and `ones_row` you do:

```
[ones_row; A]
```

This returns the following.

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

Comment: This works. But is it the best solution in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Hello, I have matrix $A,B$ of order $m\times n$, I want to write a matrix simply adding them row wise to get a $2m\times 2n$ matrix, what should I do?

Comment: I would add that `[ e1 ; e2 ]` translates to [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) whereas `[ e1 e2 ]` or `[ e1, e2 ]` translate to [`horzcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html). It is also useful to get familiar with [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) for concatenating explicitly along any dimension.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it as suggested [in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025124), however in some cases (when the matrix sizes get very big), a more memory friendly solution would be to preallocate a matrix of the correct size and use indexing to put the existing values in the correct place:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 0 ];
B = ones(size(A) + [1,0]); % Create an array of ones that is one row longer
B(2:end,:) = A;            % Replace the elements of B with elements from A
```

The reason why I say this is more memory friendly is because when we create a row of ones we need to allocate memory for a vector, and then when we concatenate we need to allocate memory **again** for the result of the concatenation. When we use indexing, there's no need to allocate an intermediate vector. It isn't really important in this example, but can be quite significant for larger matrices or operations performed thousands of times.

---

There's also a useful function in the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html) - [`padarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html):

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 0 ];
B = padarray(A,[1 0],1,'pre');
```

Answer (score -1):

I can give a solution that can worked for any matrix.

suppose your matrix is `A`, A is `m*n`

```
n = size(A,2)

out = [ones(1,n);A]
```

This solution works for any matrix.

Comment: If A has `n` columns, you cannot concatenate it with a row/s having only one column. Please read the question again.

Comment: Read again my answer, it has not any relation to size of A. A can have n columns. Concentration is true, You can test in MATLAB.

Comment: For the sake of an example:  `A = rand(5,6);` `n = size(A,2);` `out = [ones(n,1);A];` Error using vertcat. Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: Now after the edit, your answer is exactly what is already posted by David Alber. This adds nothing new to the post. Please read the already posted answers before adding yours. Thanks

Comment: ones(n,1) changed to ones(1,n)

Comment: This adds nothing new and already posted as commented earlier

Comment: The answer of David Alber can not used for all matrix. It completes his answer.

Comment: Please read again. It is exactly the same and *can* be used for all matrices. Your answer just uses different variable names

Comment: I you read Urgent's comment, He has problem with this answer.

Comment: So you decided to provide  exactly  the same solution with different variable names. Okay

Comment: @PyMatFlow Urgent's comment is completely irrelevant and it should be a new question (if anything). The original question already contains `size(A, 2)` and `ones(1, ..);` - this is why Sardar said your answer adds nothing new.

Comment: I think my solution can help MATLAB users.